# UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "train"

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have a model (`fit`), based on historic information until last month. Now I would like to predict using my model for the current month. When I try to invoke the following code:

```
predicted <- predict(fit, testData[-$Readmit])
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict'
    applied to an object of class "train"
```

**Notes:**

1. The fit model was created via: `train` function from [caret](http://topepo.github.io/caret/training.html) package, using random forest algorithm
2. The `predict` is a generic function that will invoke the specific predict function based on the first input argument. In my case it will be:

   `>fit$modelInfo$label`

   `[1] "Random Forest"`

Therefore the predict method invoked will be: [predict.randomForest](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/randomforest/docs/predict.randomForest). See [caret documentation][3] for more info.

Here the summary source code for generating the model and invoking it:

```
# Script-1: create a model:
fit <- train(testData[-$Readmit], testData$Readmit)
saveRDS(fit, modelFileName) # save the fit object into a file

# Script-2: predict
fit <- readRDS(modelFileName) # Load the model (generated previously)
predicted <- predict(fit, testData[-$Readmit])
```

**Note**: The execution time for generating the model is about 3 hours, that is why I save the object for reusing after that.

The data set from the training model as the following structure:

```
> str(fit$trainingData)
'data.frame':   29955 obs. of  27 variables:
$ Acuity                : Factor w/ 3 levels "Elective  ","Emergency ",..: 2 2 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 ...
$ AgeGroup              : Factor w/ 10 levels "100-105","65-70",..: 8 6 9 9 5 4 9 2 3 2 ...
$ IsPriority            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ QNXTReferToId         : int  115 1703712 115 3690 1948 115 109 512 481 1785596 ...
$ QNXTReferFromId       : int  1740397 1724801 1711465 1704170 1714272 1731911 1535 1712758 1740614 1760252 ...
$ iscasemanagement      : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 1 1 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 ...
$ iseligible            : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ referralservicecode   : Factor w/ 11 levels "12345","278",..: 1 1 1 9 9 1 1 6 9 9 ...
$ IsHighlight           : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ admittingdiagnosiscode: num  439 786 785 786 428 ...
$ dischargediagnosiscode: num  439 0 296 786 428 ...
$ RealLengthOfStay      : int  3 1 6 1 2 3 3 7 3 2 ...
$ QNXTPCPId             : int  1740397 1724801 1711465 1704170 1714272 1731911 1535 1712758 1740614 1760252 ...
$ QNXTProgramId         : Factor w/ 3 levels "QMXHPQ0839     ",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ physicalzipcode       : int  33054 33712 33010 33809 33010 33013 33142 33030 33161 33055 ...
$ gender                : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 ...
$ ethnicitycode         : Factor w/ 4 levels "ETHN0001       ",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
$ dx1                   : num  439 786 296 786 428 ...
$ dx2                   : num  439 292 785 786 428 ...
$ dx3                   : num  402 0 250 0 0 ...
$ svc1                  : int  0 120 120 762 762 120 120 120 762 762 ...
$ svc2                  : int  120 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ svc3                  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Disposition           : Factor w/ 28 levels "0","APPEAL & GRIEVANCE REVIEW                                   ",..: 11 11 16 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 ...
$ AvgIncome             : Factor w/ 10 levels "-1",">100k","0-25k",..: 3 6 3 8 3 4 3 5 4 4 ...
$ CaseManagerNameID     : int  124 1 1 19 20 1 16 1 43 20 ...
$ .outcome              : Factor w/ 2 levels "NO","YES": 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 1    ...
```

now the `testData` will have the following structure:

```
> str(testData[-$Readmit])
'data.frame':   610 obs. of  26 variables:
$ Acuity                : Factor w/ 4 levels "0","Elective  ",..: 3 2 4 2 2 2 4 3 3 3 ...
$ AgeGroup              : Factor w/ 9 levels "100-105","65-70",..: 4 3 5 4 2 9 4 2 4 6 ...
$ IsPriority            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 ...
$ QNXTReferToId         : int  2140 482 1703785 1941 114 1714905 1703785 98 109 109 ...
$ QNXTReferFromId       : int  1791383 1729375 1718532 1746336 1718267 1718267 1718532 98 109 109 ...
$ iscasemanagement      : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 ...
$ iseligible            : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ referralservicecode   : Factor w/ 7 levels "12345","IPMAT          ",..: 5 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 1 5 ...
$ IsHighlight           : Factor w/ 2 levels "N","Y": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ admittingdiagnosiscode: num  11440 11317 11420 11317 1361 ...
$ dischargediagnosiscode: num  11440 11317 11420 11317 1361 ...
$ RealLengthOfStay      : int  1 2 4 3 1 1 16 1 1 3 ...
$ QNXTPCPId             : int  3212 1713678 1738430 1713671 1720569 1791640 1725962 1148 1703290 1705009 ...
$ QNXTProgramId         : Factor w/ 2 levels "QMXHPQ0839     ",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ physicalzipcode       : int  34744 33175 33844 33178 33010 33010 33897 33126 33127 33125 ...
$ gender                : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 2 1 2 1 2 2 2 1 1 2 ...
$ ethnicitycode         : Factor w/ 1 level "No Ethnicity   ": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ dx1                   : num  11440 11317 11420 11317 1361 ...
$ dx2                   : num  11440 11317 11420 11317 1361 ...
$ dx3                   : num  0 1465 0 11326 0 ...
$ svc1                  : int  52648 27447 50040 27447 55866 55866 51595 0 99221 300616 ...
$ svc2                  : int  76872 120 50391 120 120 38571 120 762 120 0 ...
$ svc3                  : int  762 0 120 0 0 51999 0 0 0 762 ...
$ Disposition           : Factor w/ 14 levels "0","DENIED- Not Medically Necessary                             ",..: 3 5 3 4 3 3 5 3 3 5 ...
$ AvgIncome             : Factor w/ 10 levels "-1",">100k","0-25k",..: 6 7 5 9 3 3 6 4 3 4 ...
$ CaseManagerNameID     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 7 ...
```

The variable structure is the same, just that some factor variables has different levels because some variable has new values. For example: `Acuity` in the model has 3-levels and in the testing data 4-levels.

I don't have from upfront a way to know all possible level for all variables.

Any advice, please...

Thanks in advance,

David

Comment: `train` is not an R function. You can read its documentation like `?library_you_got_it_from::train`. They probably mention there whether it has a `predict` method.

Comment: Is this from the `caret` package?

Comment: do `summary(fit)` gives you something logical?

Comment: I added more detail in the original post based on the previous comments by ( @loiri @Frank and @ abhiieor ). @ abhiieor  the output of str(fit) provide to much information, I got from it the training data structure via: `fit$trainingData`. The only different from this and other examples I am using too, is that I am saving the variable, then loading it and the test set comes from a new file (it is not part of the train set), but with the same data structure (but not possible all same values or levels). I don't know if this is related with my problem. thanks.

Comment: Only the first @name in a comment gets pinged, fyi.

Comment: I forgot to add the library caret in the source code. That solves the original error and generates this: `Error in predict.randomForest(modelFit, newdata, type = "prob") : New factor levels not present in the training data`

That point to the suspect I have related with the levels. Now looking in Stackoverflow about this new error, I have found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17059432/random-forest-package-in-r-shows-error-during-prediction-if-there-are-new-fact) as possible solution for this new message.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think I found why this happened...The `predict` is a generic function from: `stats` package. I use the namespace `::`-notation for invoking the functions from the `caret` package (that is the recommendation for creating a user packages) and the equivalent `predict` function from `caret` package is: `predict.train`, that is an internal function, that cannot be invoked by an external application. The only way to invoke this function, is using the generic `predict` function from `stats` package, then based on the class of the first input argument: `predicted <- predict(fit, testData[-$Readmit])` it identifies the particular `predict` function will be invoked.

For this particular case the class of this function is `train`, so it would call actually the function: `train.predict` from `caret` package. This function also handles the particular function requested for prediction based on the algorithm (method) used, for example: `predict.gbm` or `predict.glm`, etc. It is explained, in detail, in the caret [documentation](http://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html) section: "5.7 Extracting Predictions and Class Probabilities".

Therefore the `::`-notation works well for other functions in the package, such as: `caret.train` for example, but not for this particular one: `predict`. In such cases it is necessary to explicitly load the library, so it internally can invoke `predict.train` function.

In short, the solution is just adding the following line before invoking the `predict` function:

```
library(caret)
```

Then error disappears.

Comment: The same thing happened to me with the `biglm` package, after having attached caret but not `biglm`, so + 1.

Answer (score 8):

Based on the answer from @David Leal, I tried loading `library(caret)` before calling the predict function but it did not help.

After trying a bit, I realized that I had to load the library that contains the model itself. In my case, I had to call `library(kenlab)` for Support Vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Came across this thread while troubleshooting a similar problem and wanted to add my solutions. In particular, the answers above involve invoking `library()` inside of a package, which is strongly discouraged as it can unknowingly alter a user's library search path and lead to namespace conflicts. My answers may be case-specific, but they worked without requiring `library()` or `require()`.

My goal was to create a package that would allow users to generate predictions from their own data using models that I had already created. These models would be hard-coded into the package. They included a `kknn` based k-nearest neighbor model and a `rpart` based decision tree model. Both were created using the `tidymodels` package.

---

Starting with the `rpart` tree model, since it was the most straightforward. When trying to run `stats::predict(hla_tree$model, new_data = df)`, I originally received the same error as OP:

```
Error in UseMethod("predict") : no applicable method for 'predict'
    applied to an object of class c("_rpart", "model_fit")
```

Fortunately, in `parsnip` (the relevant part of `tidymodels`), `predict.model_fit` is an exported object, so this could be corrected by simply changing the line to `parsnip::predict.model_fit(hla_tree$model, new_data = df)`

---

The `kknn` k-nearest neighbor model was more challenging. After getting past the initial error as described above, I would get a different error

```
Error in get(ctr, mode = "function", envir = parent.frame()): object 'contr.dummy' of mode 'function' was not found
```

This error seemed specific to the `kknn` package and how the `contr.dummy` function was referred to as a quoted object within `kknn()`. My best guess of why this occurs is based on the order of how functions were loaded from the `kknn` namespace inside of a package. Inside of a package, a call to `kknn()` would end up referring to `contr.dummy` before `contr.dummy()` had been loaded into the namespace, resulting in the error when `kknn()` was called. Outside of a package, `library(kknn)` would add `contr.dummy()` to the name space at the start, so `kknn()` would succeed.

Fortunately, this had been addressed in a [pending pull request to `kknn`](https://github.com/KlausVigo/kknn/pull/24). So I then took the following steps

- Added the pull-request-specific package to the `DESCRIPTION` file with `usethis::use_dev_package("kknn", remote = "https://github.com/KlausVigo/kknn#24")`
- Added `@import kknn` to the `roxygen` comment for my function
- Changed the relevant predict line to `stats::predict(knn_model$fit, df)`

After these steps, the package passed all the `devtools::check()` steps and seemed to be working as intended.