# Trouble downloading Keras resnet50 model in R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, rstudio

I'm trying to download the ResNet50 model from Keras in R using the following code

```
model_resnet <- application_resnet50(weights = 'imagenet')
```

The code runs for a few seconds and doesn't give any error, however rather than being a 'Model' class like other Keras models, it saves as the following class:

```
<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training.Model>
```

I can't predict anything from it or print it's summary or anything. I have the same issue if I try and run the example code from the ?application_resnet50 help page in R.

Does anyone know what this means?

R 3.5.1,
Keras 2.2.2,
Tensorflow 1.11.0

Comment: I'm wondering if we're not is some variant of this problem [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38623624/usemethodpredict-no-applicable-method-for-predict-applied-to-an-object-o)

Answer (score 0):

We're following the code from [tensorflow rstudio](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/keras/reference/application_resnet50.html) and using R 3.5.1, Keras 2.2.2, Tensorflow 1.11.0

Basically, it is working as expected. The code runs for a few seconds and if all goes right, you end up with

```
<tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training.Model>
```

It is a Model, as it says. If things don't go right, this is what is being attempted, and here a network failure:

```
    > library(keras)
    > library(tensorflow)
    > model_resnet50 <- application_resnet50()
    Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
    RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

Then is works:

```
    > model_resnet50 <- application_resnet50(weights = 'imagenet')
    Downloading data from https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning- models/releases/download/v0.2/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5
    Downloading data from https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/download/v0.2/resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5
    102858752/102853048 [==============================] - 14s 0us/step
    2018-09-30 18:20:12.316814: I 
    tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports 
    instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: 
    SSE4.1 SSE4.2
    > model_resnet50
    <tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training.Model>
```

The next part depends on where those/that elephant jpeg are or come from,
it isn't clear from the link above, though probably from image-net.org.
Anyway, absent an "elephant.jpg" in your working directory, you get:

```
    > img_path <- "elephant.jpg"
    > img <- image_load(img_path, target_size = c(224,224))
    Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 
    'elephant.jpg'
```

Get some elephant jpegs and continue following the examples and have fun.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I've got an elephant pic and pre-processed it. That's not where I'm getting the error. I'm getting the following error with predict().

> preds <- model %>% predict(x)
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "c('tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training.Model', 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.network.Network', 'tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer.Layer', 'tensorflow.python.training.checkpointable.base.CheckpointableBase', 'python.builtin.object')"

Comment: I'll find an elephant and see if I can reproduce.